C# calls DLLMain without any reason
I have simple c++ dll that is used by C# desktop application. Suddenly, without any reason C# application calls DllMian with parameter DLL_THREAD_DETACH. Application is not starting or exiting. Why this happening?
DLL function in c# application is declared:
        [DllImport(DllName, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = 
CharSet.Ansi)]
        public static extern int init(StringBuilder buff, StringBuilder data);

Dll library has DllMain with code in case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule,
    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved
)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    {
        break; }
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    {

        break;
    }
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,"Hello from Dll", "Message",MB_OK);
        
        break; }
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    {
        
        break; }

    }



    return TRUE;
}


did you read what DLL_THREAD_DETACH means ?

At some point C# code has to interact with your dll and do things, why do you think this call should not happen? The problem for why you app isn't starting isn't in here (unless your C++ dll has threads initialized as/from global variables. (You can only start using threads in the C++ part after the dll has been safely attached)

Note that C# is not calling it, it's the system kernel that does it.

"Consider calling DisableThreadLibraryCalls when receiving DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dllmain
